# Access files from path above root in PHP

Tags: php, download

I'm writing a simple upload/download page in PHP. With the following code I can see files being the content of folder above the root but it's impossible to access those files. What could be the reason?

```
$targetdir="/../cat/";    
if ($dir = @opendir($targetdir))
        {
            while ($file = readdir($dir))
            {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                echo "<td><a href=".$targetdir.$file.">".$file."</a></td>";
            }
            closedir($dir);
        }
```

Comment: I don't think so since I also have implemented uploading and that work's perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you sure? I am pretty certain the security policy on most servers would prevent you going above the root.

Comment: @garryp the issue isn't security here, it's that it's trying to do something like this ... http://example.org/../cat/somefile.txt

Comment: Is there a reason you need the files to exist outside of your webroot and not stored directly in a web accessible location?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, that's the requirement. I wish it was up to me

Comment: If the files are publicly accessible then there's really no reason to store them above the root dir. If the files need to be protected, for instance you need to be logged in to access them, then it makes sense to put them above the webroot and then server them up through PHP.

Comment: Thank you but there's no need to explain this to me. That's my teacher's requirement and I have to do it no matter how stupid it is.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access files above the web root directory, instead you will need to write a script to do this for you.

> downloadfile.php?file=somefile.txt

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file']; 

if (strpos($file, '..') !== false) {
    throw new \Exception('Illegal path requested');
}

/** 
 * this will restrict files to this directory or above as 
 * to not allow reading of files which you do not want a user to access
 */
$basePath = __DIR __ . '/../cat';

$fullPath = sprintf('%s/%s', $basePath, $file);

/** check to see if the file exists and is readable **/
if (false === is_readable($fullPath)) {
    throw \Exception('file does not exist or is not accessible');
}

echo file_get_contents($file);
exit;
```

You must be very cautious when doing this, as you could allow someone to access files you don't want them to, including your source code, so make sure you're sanitizing the input.

As well you should change `$target` dir to the following, as it stands you're trying to go to the absolute root of the file system instead relative to the file which started the execution.

```
/** relative to the file that started the execution **/
$targetdir = "../cat/"

/** relative to the file that contains this variable declaration**/
$target = __DIR__ . "/../cat/"
```

Comment: when I change it, it does not print the file list anymore. Moreover, even if I hard-code '/' in part printing the list and skip it in direct links to files it changes nothing.

Comment: oops I misread the question, as @garryp mentioned it's a security issue. You need to make the user and/or group your webserver is running under has permissions to write to that directory

Comment: I can write to that dir since the upload part of my .php works properly

Comment: Woah, please don't do this, ever. This would allow anyone to access any readable file on your server.

Comment: @JonStirling of course if that was the ONLY thing in the downloadfile.php it would be very bad, as I mentioned DIRECTLY below the code.

Comment: @Augwa Sure, you've told them to sanitise the path, but not provided any hint to how, just some very insecure code. Also, /etc/sudoers for example is a sane value in this case, I suspect you meant filtering with a white list or something, but it's only a guess.

Comment: Unless you're running apache under root (which would be even worse), you wouldn't even be able to read that file as it's typically rw only by root. As for the insecurity of this, I'll amend to deal with it a bit better as to not catch someone who doesn't read into using a really bad piece of code.

Comment: Unfortunately: "Warning: file_get_contents(../cat/test.txt): failed to open stream(...)"

Comment: @PramusPL that likely means there's a permission issue, try running the new code I provided, which checks to see if the file exists beforehand, also note the security change I've also applied, so instead of passing `../cat/test.txt` you will now just pass `text.txt`

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, I just started PHP. There's a syntax error at "$basePath = __DIR __ '/../cat';". I tried doing "$basePath = __DIR __.'/../cat';" instead and it goes the same.

Comment: yes the correction you made is correct, but what you do you mean it goes the same? you get the same warning. That tells me there's a permission issue, change `file_exists` for `is_readable`, which checks to see if the file exists and it's readable.

Comment: NetBeans screams that the syntax is incorrect. When I try to run it anyway, the error I get is following:
Warning: file_get_contents(../cat/test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in (mypath)\download.php on line 5
where 5th line being
"if (strpos($file, '..') !== false) {"

Comment: anyway the issue is permissions at this point now as previously mentioned by @garryp